# Open Source alternative to Wit.ai

Tags: open-source, language, speech-recognition, voice-command

Are there some open source alternatives to what Wit.ai does, i.e. mapping voice/text queries to actions by defining recognition patterns?

(Wit.ai has an open API, but source code is closed, making it inappropriate for education purposes.)

Comment: Is it English-only?

Comment: So far as I know, wit.ai is english-only, but i wouldn't mimd if thw alternative is multilingual. Or in some other language (preferably in latimic script for the sake of redability); if the approach to the prblem is probabilistic it isn't really cruical whether is english or not - it should be easy enough to modify some of the parameters, rarher than rewriting logics tiwd up to semantics of a specific language.m

Answer (score 2):

Baidu Research released [yesterday](http://slashdot.org/story/16/01/17/1318228/baidu-releases-open-source-artificial-intelligence-code) the [code](https://github.com/baidu-research/warp-ctc) for its speech recognition library using [Connectionist Temporal Classification](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~graves/icml_2006.pdf) implemented with Torch.

Benchmarks from [Gigaom](https://gigaom.com/2014/12/18/baidu-claims-deep-learning-breakthrough-with-deep-speech/):

[image]

Comment: Very cool, but CTC is just one part of a speech recognition system. You also need the rest of the network, and a huge amount of training data. Baidu used 10k hours of transcribed audio, expended to 100k hours with noise.

Comment: @Timmmm  Good point. Some other pointers: [Decent speech recognition software for Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/256138/16704)

Answer (score 1):

[Snips.ai](https://snips.ai/) is an alternative now (2019).  Open source and privacy respecting.  Their code is on [github](https://github.com/snipsco/)

#### Edit:

their console is not open source anymore since it was aquired by sonos.

Comment: It served my purpose well, but they decided to close public access to the developer console https://forum.snips.ai/t/important-message-regarding-the-snips-console/4145, which makes it less useful as some key parts of the code were closed source.

Answer (score 0):

There are no open source alternatives. [Kaldi](http://kaldi.sourceforge.net/) is probably the best open source speech recognition system, but it is *extremely* non-trivial to set up (I still haven't managed it actually). I've used [Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) in the past but it is very low quality (think 2000's-era speech recognition - i.e. before it was any good).

As for the NLP side of things, what I call "intent recognition", I haven't looked into it that much, but Stanford's [CoreNLP](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) may be a good place to start. Again I expect it to be extremely non-trivial.

There are two similar closed-source alternatives - [Nuance Mix](http://whatsnext.nuance.com/developers/introducing-nuance-mix-for-developers/), and [Houndify](https://www.houndify.com/), but as of now (Feb, 2016), they are both effectively closed betas (Houndify doesn't let you create custom commands yet, and Nuance hasn't opened their HTTP API, though you can access it via Android or iOS).